# Equivalent balanced parentheses grammars

Tags: grammar

I have these 2 unambiguous grammars for balanced parentheses.

```
S -> S(S) | epsilon
```

and

```
S -> (S)S | epsilon
```

Are they equivalent? I have been trying some random inputs and I think they are, but I'm not sure if there is a case where one cannot reads a certain input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They recognise the same language but generate different parse trees.